# %d specifier for an uninitialized character array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    char a[8];    
    printf("%d\n",a) ;    
    return 0;    
}
```

For the above code the output was this :- 2686744

What is the reason behind this output?
I found that the output doesn't depend on the content of the array, but on the size of the array.I just want the explanation.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) for explanation

Comment: UB because your array contains garbage values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char a[8];    
printf("%d\n",a);
```

This code has undefined behavior.

The array expression `a` is implicitly converted to a `char*` value, equivalent to `&a[0]`. That value is then passed to `printf` -- but since the `%d` format requires an `int` argument, the behavior is undefined.

If `int` and `char*` happen to have the same size, and if they're passed as function arguments using the same mechanism, then it will likely print a decimal representation of the address of (the initial element of) the array.

But don't do that. If you want to print the address:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the address of the array as an integer.

If you compile with `-Wall` to enable warnings your compiler should complain about that.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you!